# Can I modally present a view controller that is part of a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have a table view and a map view that need to display the same detail controller. 
The detail controller is currently embedded in a navigation controller with the table view (I believe it is still using the auto-generated segue from the master-detail template).

I plan to have my map annotations segue to the proper detail controller, but just for testing I put a UIButton on the MKMapView and made a modal segue to the detailViewController through the storyboard.

When I run the app, the button on the map view does nothing and no errors are thrown/loggeed. 
I know you don't have to be in a navigation controller to modally present a view controller, so am I not allowed to modally present a view controller that is part of a navigation controller?

Do I need to take the detail controller out of the storyboard nav controller and push it on to the navigation stack manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace storyboard segues with coded segues:

create in each source controller a property destinationVC and initialise it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  UIViewController* dest;
self.dest = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destinationID"];
```

Don't forget to set the identifier in storyboard for the destinationID.

To segue modal:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.dest animated:YES];
```

To push:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.dest animated:YES];
```

You should be careful at the dest VC when you segue back.

```
if ([self.parentViewController.modalViewController isEqual:self]) {
   //Modal
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} else {
   //Push
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't mention if I can present a modal controller that is embedded in a navigation controller though. And a push segue requires the parent to be in a nav controller too. (Which is what my workaround is based on)

Comment: Normally you can present modals from anywhere, push only works from a navcontroller.